# DM user via slash command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

I'm making my bot cooler with slash commands and I want to add a function where the bot DMs the user of the slash command. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459079/discord-js-sending-dm-in-response-to-users-slash-commands) but that's totally useless to me because I use Python and that uses JS.

```py
@tree.command(name="dm", description="a command to DM", guild=discord.Object(id=ID)) #slashy
async def dm(interaction=discord.Interaction):
    user = discord.Object(bot.user.id)
    await user.send("This is a test message")
```

And that doesn't work because `discord.Object object has no attribute 'send'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py send a dm to a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421394/discord-py-send-a-dm-to-a-user)

Comment: The comment above is right, but on another note: `bot.user.id` is your bot, hence **bot.user**, not the person that invoked the command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.create_dm()` method:

```py
user = await interaction.user.create_dm()
await user.send("This is a test message")
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work for you.